# ifstream operator >> uint16_t sets failbit

Tags: c++, file, stl

i'm trying to ready a binary-file into a set of variables using the c++ `std::ifstream` class.

The following example works:

```
std::ifstream inFile;
inFile.open("example.bin");
uint8_t temp8;
uint16_t temp16;
inFile >> temp8;
inFile >> temp8;
```

But if i replace the last two lines with one line

```
inFile >> temp16;
```

nothing is read and `inFile.fail()` returns `true`.

Can anyone explain, why I can't read into a 16 bit variable?

Comment: Hang on while I hack into your computer and inspect the contents of `example.bin`

Comment: example.bin contains more than 16bit, thats why reading two uint8_t works.

Comment: Are you trying to read 2 bytes into `uint16_t`? That's not how `operator>>` works, it is a formatted input operation, meaning it reads a string such as `"1234"` and converts it to the number `1234`, it doesn't read 16 bits into a 16-bit data type. So it's probably failing because you have binary data that can't be interpreted as the string representation of a number. Reading into an 8-bit type works because it just reads a single byte.

Comment: @dyp, it's probably not overflowing, just failing to read binary data using a formatted input function

Comment: yeah that's exactly what i'm trying to do. in the binary file a sequence of 16bit long numbers is saved and i want to read them.

Comment: @JonathanWakely Oh, so you've already finished hacking? ;)

Comment: Then you can't use `operator>>` you need to use `istream::read()` to read two bytes. You can't read binary data using `operator>>`

Comment: ok thanks. I thougt the operator>> just reads the size of the datatype byte.

Comment: @JonathanWakely *"Reading into an 8-bit type works because it just reads a single byte."* Is it guaranteed that `uint8_t` is treated as a character type wrt streams?

Comment: @dyp, `char` must be at least 8 bits, and `short` must be at least 16 bits (see 5.4.2.1 in the C standard) so if the implementation provides `uint8_t` (which is not guaranteed) then it must be a typedef for either `char` (if that is unsigned on the platform) or `unsigned char`, it can't be another integral type.

Comment: @dyp, sorry, that C section number should be 5.2.4.2.1

Comment: @JonathanWakely It can't be an extended integer type?

Comment: @dyp, possibly, but who cares, extended integer types don't exist as far as I'm concerned, I've certainly never met one. And it would be odd for an implementation that can support 8-bit types to make `char` larger than 8 bits and then add an extended integer type with 8 bits. Why not just make `char` be the 8-bit type?

Comment: @JonathanWakely What I had in mind was making `char` an 8-bit data type and `uint8_t` a typedef of a *different* 8-bit type (not `char` nor `unsigned char` but something like `__uint8`).

Comment: @dyp, yeah, I think that would be conforming then.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `operator>>` overload for reading `uint16_t` from istreams is a formatted input function, meaning does not read binary data, it reads a string and if necessary converts it to a number (e.g. using `strtoul` or similar).

As explained at http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_istream

> The class template `basic_istream` provides support for high level input operations on character streams. The supported operations include formatted input (e.g. integer values or whitespace-separated characters and characters strings) and unformatted input (e.g. raw characters and character arrays).

`inFile >> temp16` tries to read a sequence of (usually) ASCII digits, up to the first non-digit character, then converts that sequence of digits to a number, and if it fits in `uint16_t` stores it in `temp16`.  If you are reading from a binary file then the istream is probably not going to find a sequence of ASCII digits, so reading fails.

You need to use an unformatted input function to read 16 bits directly from the file without trying to interpret a string as a number, like:

```
inFile.read(reinterpret_cast<char*>(&temp16), 2);
```

Answer (score 2):

The extraction of an integer from a stream with `>>` expects to find ascii numeric digits.  If it doesn't find them, it sets the fail status.

If your `uint16_t` data is not by pure coincidence composed by two bytes, which the first appear to be between 0x30 and 0x39, it's doomed to fail.  ANd if it would succed, it wouldn't be the values that you expect.

For binary data use:

```
    inFile.read (&temp16, sizeof(temp16));
```

and of course, open the file with `ios::binary` mode.