# Why can't I input an integer from the istream? *Error on starred input operators*

Tags: c++

```
istream& operator>>(istream& is, State& s){
    uint16_t first;
    int second;
    char delim;
    is **>>** first >> delim >> second >> delim; //For player in Room.
    for(GameObject* i : GameObject::GameObjects){
        is **>>** first >> delim >> second >> delim;
        s.containerObjects.insert(pair<int, int>(first, second));
    }
    s.containerObjects.insert(pair<int, int>(first, second));
    return is;
}
```

The starred input operators are giving me an error from clang: 'Invalid operands to binary expression (std::istream and uint16_t).

The data in the file looks like so:

0:1|2:2|3:4|

Can anyone help me to understand why?

Thanks!

Edit: Original operator usage:

```
file >> currentState;
```

Comment: see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30550887/ifstream-operator-uint16-t-sets-failbit

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I didn't include iostream... however I was still able to use istream and ostream with basic strings, so I guess that is a built in thing?

Answer (score 0):

Error message: 'Invalid operands to binary expression (std::istream and uint16_t) says it all. There is no >> operator defined for type uint16_t. Try >> into a normal int type and then static_cast<unint16_t> the value and put it in your variable "first".

Comment: Thanks for your prompt reply :) I have tried using a normal int type, however, the error message just changes to 'Invalid operands to binary expression (std::istream and int)' The only type that seems to get rid of the error is std::string.